# Image view from view pager shared elemen wrong exit transition

Tags: android, android-layout, shared-element-transition

Im am trying to do a smooth and nice animation but I'm having this problem:

https://streamable.com/09yjl

The first imageView' screen has scaleType="centerCrop" and I think this is the problem. Any solution for fix the exit animation scaling?

I open fullScreenActivity with this code:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, view1, "itemImageTransition");
    startActivity(new Intent(context, FullScreenImageActivity.class), options.toBundle());
});
```

and viewpager layout is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:transitionName="itemImageTransition" />
```

and the fullScreen layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<it.tcconsulting.cyclone.utils.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transitionName="itemImageTransition" />
```